# Arrays not working in AIX KSH

Tags: shell, unix, sh, ksh, aix

I have code:

```
typeset -i idx=0
for each in `find . -name "*.log" -print `
do
        ILIST[idx]=`basename $each`
        idx=idx+1
        print :${ILIST[$idx]}:$each:$idx  << does not print array element "::file1.log:o"
done    # for each

print ${ILIST[@]}  << prints entire array as expected
exit
```

So, how can you print the single element of an array?  It works in HPUX.  The goal is to create 2 arrays side-by-side where one is filename and other is time created so that the time can be checked for that file.

Comment: You assign something to array element `idx` but then you increment it and print element `idx+1` which is always empty at that point. Simply increment at the very end of the loop...

Comment: I'd generally suggest avoiding the dependency on `typeset -i` by using  POSIX-compliant math syntax (`idx=$((idx + 1 ))`) --  that way a reader doesn't have to pay as much attention to context to be sure your code works correctly.

Comment: As a different issue, though -- `for each in $(find ...)` is broken on its face; doesn't handle file or directory names with spaces, wildcards, etc. See [UsingFind](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind#Actions_in_bulk:_xargs.2C_-print0_and_-exec_.2B-) for a discussion of better practices -- while it's a bash-centric document, it does discuss compatibility of each pattern shown with different shells and different versions of `find`. Similarly, [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) applies even here.

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't have access to an AIX box to test if the syntax is good, but it works well on a Linux implementation.

Since KSH supports compound variable (93l +) I think you would be better using them instead of 2 arrays.

Here's a snippet of code that would do what you want (at least I think :) )

```
    #!/bin/ksh

    typeset -L50 Col1
    typeset -L25 Col2

    #need to give the path as a parameter here since it's a test script
    DIRNAME=$1

    idx=0
    #The caveat for "find" still apply, so I'm assuming there is no special characters nor space in the filenames
    for file in $(find $DIRNAME -type f -name "*.log")
    do
    #Full path name
            LOGFILE[$idx].FName=$file
    #Only File name
            LOGFILE[$idx].BName=$(basename $file)
    #Last modification time since the beginning of time in second as it is easier to manage afterward. There is no creation date per se on Linux at least
            LOGFILE[$idx].MDate=$(stat -c %Z $file)
            ((idx++))
    done

    Col1="Filename"
    Col2="Date"

    print "$Col1$Col2\n"

    #Some prefer the syntax ${#LOGFILE[@]} but won't make a difference here since it's an indexed array.
    for ((i=0;i<${#LOGFILE[*]};i++)); do
            Col1=${LOGFILE[$i].BName}
    #Translating the seconds to human date. Format can of course be modified at will
            Col2=$(date -d @"${LOGFILE[$i].MDate}" +"%Y%m%d%H%M")
            print "$Col1$Col2"
    done
```

Hope it helps.